# Web Scraping Dynamic Pages - Adjusting the code

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, element

[αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7658985/%CE%B1%D4%8B%C9%B1%D2%BD%D4%83-%CE%B1%D0%BC%D1%94%D1%8F%CE%B9c%CE%B1%CE%B7) helped me in constructing this code for scraping reviews from this page where reviews are dynamically loaded. I then tried to adjust it so that it scrapes not just the comment-body, but also the commentors' names, dates, and ratings, and for the code to save the extracted data into an excel file. But I failed to do so. Could someone help me in adjusting the code correctly?

This is the code from [αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7658985/%CE%B1%D4%8B%C9%B1%D2%BD%D4%83-%CE%B1%D0%BC%D1%94%D1%8F%CE%B9c%CE%B1%CE%B7)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import math


def PageNum():
    r = requests.get(
        "https://boxes.mysubscriptionaddiction.com/box/boxycharm?ratings=true#review-update-create")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    num = int(
        soup.find("a", class_="show-more-reviews").text.split(" ")[3][1:-1])
    if num % 3 == 0:
        return (num / 3) + 1
    else:
        return math.ceil(num / 3) + 2


def Main():
    num = PageNum()
    headers = {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for item in range(1, num):
            print(f"Extracting Page# {item}")
            r = req.get(
                f"https://boxes.mysubscriptionaddiction.com/get_user_reviews?box_id=105&page={item}", headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            for com in soup.findAll("div", class_=r'\"comment-body\"'):
                print(com.text[5:com.text.find(r"\n", 3)])


Main()
```

This is the code I adjusted but then got errors that I couldn't resolve

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import math
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

def PageNum():
    r = requests.get(
        "https://boxes.mysubscriptionaddiction.com/box/boxycharm?ratings=true#review-update-create")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    num = int(
        soup.find("a", class_="show-more-reviews").text.split(" ")[3][1:-1])
    if num % 3 == 0:
        return (num / 3) + 1
    else:
        return math.ceil(num / 3) + 2


def Main():
    num = PageNum()
    headers = {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for item in range(1, num):
            names = []
            headers = []
            bodies = []
            ratings = []
            published = []
            updated = []
            reported = []
            dateElements = []
            print(f"Extracting Page# {item}")
            r = req.get(
                f"https://boxes.mysubscriptionaddiction.com/get_user_reviews?box_id=105&page={item}", headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            for com in soup.findAll("div", class_=r'\"user-review\"'):
                names.append(article.find('div', attrs={'class': 'name'}).text.strip())
                try:
                    bodies.append(article.find('div', attrs={'class': 'comment-body'}).text.strip())
                except:
                    bodies.append('NA')

                try:
                    ratings.append(article.find('meta', attrs={'itemprop': 'ratingValue'})['content'])
                except:
                    ratings.append('NA')
                dateElements.append(article.find('div', attrs={'class': 'comment-date'}).text.strip())
                print(com.text[5:com.text.find(r"\n", 3)])

            temp_df = pd.DataFrame(
                {'User Name': names, 'Body': bodies, 'Rating': ratings, 'Published Date': dateElements})
            df = df.append(temp_df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

Main()

df.to_csv('Allure10.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
print ('excel done')
```

Comment: Where did you define article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import math
import csv


def PageNum():
    r = requests.get(
        "https://boxes.mysubscriptionaddiction.com/box/boxycharm?ratings=true#review-update-create")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    num = int(
        soup.find("a", class_="show-more-reviews").text.split(" ")[3][1:-1])
    if num % 3 == 0:
        return (num / 3) + 1
    else:
        return math.ceil(num / 3) + 2


def Main():
    num = PageNum()
    headers = {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    with requests.Session() as req:
        names = []
        dates = []
        comments = []
        rating = []
        for item in range(1, num):
            print(f"Extracting Page# {item}")
            r = req.get(
                f"https://boxes.mysubscriptionaddiction.com/get_user_reviews?box_id=105&page={item}", headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            for com in soup.findAll("div", class_=r'\"comment-body\"'):
                comments.append(com.text[5:com.text.find(r"\n", 3)])
            for name in soup.findAll("div", class_=r'\"name\"'):
                names.append(name.text[:name.text.find(r"<\/div>", 1)])
            for date in soup.findAll("div", class_=r'\"comment-date\"'):
                dates.append(date.text[:date.text.find(r"<\/div>", 1)])
            for rate in soup.findAll("meta", itemprop=r'\"ratingValue\"'):
                rating.append(rate.get("content")[2:-3])
    return zip(names, dates, rating, comments)


def Save():
    data = Main()
    with open("oka.csv", 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Name", "Dates", "Rating", "Comments"])
        writer.writerows(data)


Save()
```

Output: [check-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/d7528470a5432d8179f047c33d239329/oka.csv)

[image]

Comment: How to fix this?
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sara Jitkresorn/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/SubsAddict.py", line 53, in <module>
    Save()
  File "C:/Users/Sara Jitkresorn/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/SubsAddict.py", line 50, in Save
    writer.writerows(data)
  File "C:\Users\Sara Jitkresorn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp874.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f922' in position 530: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: @SaraJitkresorn i believe that you are using a `Windows`? with `VSCode`?

Comment: I am using Windows. I am sorry but I do not know what VSCode is.

Comment: @SaraJitkresorn how do you run your code ? which `interpreter` you using ?

Comment: I'm running the code through Pycharm with Python 3.7 as the interpreter

Comment: @SaraJitkresorn copy updated code. and update me with the result